# Cannot send requests to private EC2 WebServer from another EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

So I want to set up a REST API which will ONLY be used by other EC2 instances in my private AWS network.

I finished writing the code, configured a new EC2 instance with an apache web server and started it. Also I made sure that the WebServer instance accepts requests to port 80 from anywhere.

I then log into another EC2 instance, in the same private network. I do a CURL call to the private address (specified by doing http://10.100.18.19, but this is no the actual address I just made it up to put here as an example) but the connection times out.

So I tried the same thing to another web server (this one actually connected to a load balanceer and hosting fully working web page which I can browse to, so I know it's working fine) and the same thing happens.

This tells me that I need to do something in order to let my ec2 instances connect to the web server inside the private network.

Can anyone tell me what could be happening and how I could fix it?

EDIT:

All machines are in the same VPC and in the same subnet.
The maching doing the request is the Bastion to my system and I connects to the WebServer via SSH in order to install/configure/etc

Comment: is it in the same vpc? subnet?  we need to know more about your network.

Comment: Yes. They are in the same VPC and subnet. I verified it and also I acces the webserver. I edited the question to reflect this. Thank you

Comment: have you configured the security group of the webserver to explicitly permit traffic from the bastion host?  Being on the same subnet is meaningless if you have not explicitly permitted traffic via a security group.

Comment: @mcfinnigan I was absolutely sure I had. It was the secornd thing I check and I even comment it in the question. But upon a second inspection the security group had the source weird. So I created a new one, added it to the EC2 instance and the problem was fixed!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: @aarelovich you will not believe how many times that particular behaviour of EC2 has bittin me in the pants.  Glad it's sorted :D

Comment: @mcfinnigan Yeahhh I know AWS is really really powerfull, but to be honest, a lot of times feels too complex for its own good